# C code in HTML page

Tags: html, c

I have some C code with

```
#include <stdio.h>
```

which should be shown on a web page. For this issue I use tag `pre` and `code` but unfortunately the angle brackets disappear.

```
#include stdio.h
```

What can I do to show the `stdio.h` with angle brackets?

Comment: Use `&lt;` and `&gt;` ?

Comment: For a list of characters https://www.freeformatter.com/html-entities.html

Comment: This question's own page source renders the angled brackets in the question with `#include &amp;lt;stdio.h&amp;gt;` but when I made a simple test page my browser did not render it correctly, although it did when using @EugeneSh. comment. Anyway this isn't a question about C. I have mistakenly thought that the `<code>` tag allowed you to post unadulterated code.

Comment: . . . but the page source code does not use the `<code>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because HTML will treat ‘<‘ as opening tag and will try to render it. You need to convert all the applicable characters to their HTML entities to prevent this, for example 
For showing ‘<‘ you need to convert it to ‘&lt;’ and for ‘>’ you need to convert it to ‘&gt;’. There are some other characters which you will need to encode, some languages have built in function for this, example in PHP you can use ‘htmlentities()’ function.

Answer (score 0):

Use a verbatim `<[CDATA[` your C code `]]>` in your HTML page, to nest your C code.  This allows all but the sequence `]]>` in the quoted block.